# What's the meaning of "all but unsuring runs by publicity-hungry outsiders" ? Thanks!

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage, phrases

Here is the entire phrase : "As the 2020 race, the party deferred to measures of popular sentiment to determine who should make the cut for the debates, all but unsuring runs by publicity-hungry outsiders"

I'm also uncertain about the expression "make the cut" ; here, does it mean participate to the debates or win the debates ?

Thanks you,

Comment: Are you sure it wasn’t ‘ensuring’ rather than ‘unsuring’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printed source? All searches show it as 'ensuring', just a typo. **Make the cut** is used to describe individuals selected for a limited space. (Example: 5 out of 100 performers who auditioned "made the cut" to continue to the next round of the competition.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's from The Atlantic issue of December 2019, but it's my bad, it's indeed "ensuring". So, in other words : in doing so, the 2020 race let outsider people who are looking for publicity run the debates ?